# Compress Pdf using c++

Tags: c++, pdf

I have a c++ application in Qt where I create a pdf file. How can I compress the pdf file so it is smaller. Is there a free c++ lib that is available and easy to use?

Comment: I don't know anything about how pdf data is internally stored so it is quite possible that they already do some lossless compression which would make it hard to compress further. However, you can check out zlib. It is a standard C++ compression library. It is worth noting it only does compression, it doesn't handle .zip file structure, but they do include an interface for doing that (I think it is called minzip or something like that)

Comment: Have you tried [zlib](http://www.zlib.net)?

Answer (score 0):

Two usual methods:

1. `qCompress` \ `qUncompress` from the `QByteArray` class let you do that. Just read the content of a `QFile` with `readAll` or as you please, and then use these methods: [qCompress](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbytearray.html#qCompress). This is clearly the easiest solution, but are somehow tied to Qt, and cannot easily export to a specific format
2. 7zip which is licenced under LGPL, and which you can integrate as sources files, or as a library : [7zip](http://www.7-zip.org/), and the [download page](http://www.7-zip.org/download.html) with sources. A bit more involving, but let you compress and uncompress in various formats, as long as you are fine with 7zip license (to put it in perspective, Qt OpenSource is at the time mostly LGPLv3)

However, as hinted by RyanP, don't expect a huge compression ratio, as PDF are already compressed. A quick test on a 920kB PDF with basic 7zip compression yielded a 860kB file, corresponding to a only 6.5% compression.